# How can I control the order that emails are sent from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I am trying to control the order that emails are sent from a web site.

I have code that sends email1 and email2 using the same mechanism : System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

The emails always arrive in the order email2, email1 (even if I send them email2 and email1).

I have tried setting the timeout properties as suggested here
http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=166439&.

like this

Public Class SmtpClientAdapter
Inherits SmtpClient

```
Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal message As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)

    Host = Parameter.Data.GetString("SMTPServer")
    message.IsBodyHtml = True

    MyBase.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1
    MyBase.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1
    MyBase.Send(message)

End Sub
```

End Class

I have been trying to discover is I can make use of the SMTP header deferred-delivery

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.65

Does anyone know if I can use this header from ASP.NET?

Derek

Comment: I agree that the header has to be honoured by the server - but does anyone know how to set the header and had any experience of it working or not?

In an ideal world email2 should be delayed by a couple of hours if we could use this header.

Answer (score 5):

It is not ASP.NETs responsibility to handle the deferred-delivery header.  Its up to the SMTP server to which you send the email to choose support that header.

Generally speaking you cannot realistically expect to control the sequence of email delivery.